# regex is returning null or the search expression

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

im trying to get the file name like `11020001588_20210127175414319.wav` from the string `file:////media//devion//recordings//voicemail//1/102/000/11020001588/11020001588_20210127175414319.wav`

the method im using

```
regExtractFile(filepath) {
    RegExp filename = RegExp(
        (r'([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).wav'));
    Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = filename.allMatches(filepath);
    matches.forEach((match) {
      print(filename.toString().substring(match.start, match.end));
    });
  }
```

when i run this method i get output like

```
I/flutter (18734): -9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9
I/flutter (18734): null
I/flutter (18734): -9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9
I/flutter (18734): null
I/flutter (18734): -9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9
```

i cant try subString to extract file path as all the strins are different with file name as common, new to dart and regex, all help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: `filename.toString()` converts the regular expression to a string, not the match.

Comment: You should be using `filepath.substring(...)`

Comment: Doesn't Dart have functions for parsing pathnames? You shouldn't need a regexp to get the filename from a pathname.

Comment: And `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` can be simplified to `[0-9]{11}`

Comment: @Barmar i tried .substring, but it says subString is not defined for type regexp

Comment: `filepath` isn't a regexp, `filename` is. Maybe you should name your variables better to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use path to get the file name

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as filePath;
import 'dart:io';
```

Get the file name first

```
File file = new File("file:////media//devion//recordings//voicemail//1/102/000/11020001588/11020001588_20210127175414319.wav");
String basename = filePath.basename(file.path);
```

Then checking:

```
RegExp regExp = RegExp((r'([0-9]{11}\_[0-9]{17})\.wav'));
print("$filename ; hasMatch : ${regExp.hasMatch(filename)}");
```

I don't sure this is you want

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `substring()`. Match group 0 is the part of the input that matched the regexp.

```
    matches.forEach((match) {
      print(match.group(0));
    });
```